# Rendering Model inside Model ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I tried to render model in View with Html.EditorForModel.
This is code of my Model.
Product class

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int DealerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DealerId")]
    public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

Dealer class

```
public class Dealer
{
    [Key]
    public int DealerId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DealerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I try do render Product for editing. I do it this way

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Product"))
{        
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model.Dealer)
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="edit" />
}
```

But it seems like View render EditorForModel() twice. This is screen
[image: View Edit]

Is it way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you're calling `@Html.EditorForModel` twice. Try this instead :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Product"))
{        
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dealer)
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="edit" />
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is work. Unfortunately i have not enough reputation to mark your answer as useful. But thx again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead Using `@Html.EditorForModel()` twice use it single time..